# Android Camera: setParameters exception on Android

Tags: android, android-camera

**Hi**.

I got this error:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
>   setParameters failed

The error log shows that all `camera.setParameters(parameters)` causes the crash.

**Here's my code:**

```
android.hardware.Camera camera;
      public class CameraActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback , GestureDetector.OnGestureListener{
        android.hardware.Camera camera;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
            Fabric.with(this, new Answers());
            setContentView(R.layout.camera_activity);

            } else {
            }
            ButterKnife.inject(this);
            surfaceHolder=surfaceView.getHolder();
            surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
            surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
            imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
    cameraImage();
                }
            });
            callback = new android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onPictureTaken(byte[] bytes, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
                    FileOutputStream outputStream=null;
                    File file_image = getDirc();
                    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmms");
                    String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
                    String photo_file="PI_"+date+".jpg";
                    String file_name = file_image.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+photo_file;
                    File picfile=new File(file_name);
                    try {
                        outputStream=new FileOutputStream(picfile);
                        outputStream.write(bytes);
                        outputStream.close();
                    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){}
                    catch (IOException ex){}
                    finally {
                    }
                    refreshCamera();
                    refreshGallery(picfile);
                    try {
                        camera.stopPreview();
                    }catch (Exception e){}
                    try{
                        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                        camera.startPreview();
                    }catch (Exception e){}
                }
            };
            }
        private void refreshGallery(File file){
            Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
        }
        public void refreshCamera(){
            if (surfaceHolder.getSurface() == null){
                return;
            }
        }
        private File getDirc(){
    File dics = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
            return new File(dics ,"Camera");
        }
        public void cameraImage(){
            camera.takePicture(null , null ,callback);
           MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this , R.raw.sound);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder ) {
    try {
        camera = android.hardware.Camera.open();
    }catch (RuntimeException ex){}
            android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters;
            parameters = camera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(60);
            parameters.setPreviewSize(1920 , 1080);
            parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            try {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                camera.startPreview();
            }catch (Exception e){
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            refreshCamera();
            setDisplayOrientation();
        }
        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
            camera=null;
        }
        public void frontCamera(View view) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
            camera=null;
            if (cameraId == 0){
                try {
                    camera = android.hardware.Camera.open(1);
                }catch (RuntimeException ex){}
                android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters;
                parameters = camera.getParameters();
                parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(60);
                parameters.setPreviewSize(1920 , 1080);
                parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                camera.setParameters(parameters);
                camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                cameraId = 1;
                try {
                    camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                    camera.startPreview();
                }catch (Exception e){
                }
            }
            else{
                try {
                    camera = android.hardware.Camera.open();
                }catch (RuntimeException ex){}
                android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters;
                parameters = camera.getParameters();
                parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(60);
                parameters.setPreviewSize(1920 , 1080);
                parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                camera.setParameters(parameters);
                camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                cameraId = 0;
                try {
                    camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                    camera.startPreview();
                }catch (Exception e){
                }
            }
            }
        private void setDisplayOrientation() {
            // Now set the display orientation:
            mDisplayRotation = Util.getDisplayRotation(CameraActivity.this);
            mDisplayOrientation = Util.getDisplayOrientation(mDisplayRotation, 0);
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(mDisplayOrientation);
            if (mFaceView != null) {
                mFaceView.setDisplayOrientation(mDisplayOrientation);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onShowPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
        {
            switch(event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    x1 = event.getX();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    x2 = event.getX();
                    float deltaX = x2 - x1;
                    if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE)
                    {
                        // Left to Right swipe action
                        if (x2 > x1)
                        {
                        }
                        // Right to left swipe action
                        else
                        {
                            camera.stopPreview();
                            camera.release();
                            camera=null;
                           //this one
                            if(moi == 0){
                                moi = 1;
                            if (cameraId == 1){
                                try {
                                    camera = android.hardware.Camera.open(1);
                                }catch (RuntimeException ex){}
                                android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters;
                                parameters = camera.getParameters();
                                parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_SEPIA);
                                parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(60);
                                parameters.setPreviewSize(1920 , 1080);
                                parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                                camera.setParameters(parameters);
                                camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                                cameraId = 1;
                                try {
                                    camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                                    camera.startPreview();
                                }catch (Exception e){
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                try {
                                    camera = android.hardware.Camera.open();
                                }catch (RuntimeException ex){}
                                android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters;
                                parameters = camera.getParameters();
                                parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(60);
                                parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_SEPIA);
                                parameters.setPreviewSize(1920, 1080);
                                parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                                camera.setParameters(parameters);
                                camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                                cameraId = 0;
                                try {
                                    camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                                    camera.startPreview();
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                }
                            }
                            }
                       else if(moi == 1){
                            moi = 2;
                            if (cameraId == 1){
                                try {
                                    camera = android.hardware.Camera.open(1);
                                }catch (RuntimeException ex){}
                                android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters;
                                parameters = camera.getParameters();
                                parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_AQUA);
                                parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(60);
                                parameters.setPreviewSize(1920 , 1080);
                                parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                                camera.setParameters(parameters);
                                camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                                cameraId = 1;
                                try {
                                    camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                                    camera.startPreview();
                                }catch (Exception e){
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                try {
                                    camera = android.hardware.Camera.open();
                                }catch (RuntimeException ex){}
                                android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters;
                                parameters = camera.getParameters();
                                parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(60);
                                parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_AQUA);
                                parameters.setPreviewSize(1920, 1080);
                                parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                                camera.setParameters(parameters);
                                camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                                cameraId = 0;
                                try {
                                    camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                                    camera.startPreview();
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                }}
                            }
                        else if(moi == 2){
                        moi = 3;
                        if (cameraId == 1){
                            try {
                                camera = android.hardware.Camera.open(1);
                            }catch (RuntimeException ex){}
                            android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters;

                            parameters = camera.getParameters();
                            parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_BLACKBOARD);
                            parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(60);
                            parameters.setPreviewSize(1920 , 1080);
                            parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                            camera.setParameters(parameters);
                            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                            cameraId = 1;
                            try {
                                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                                camera.startPreview();
                            }catch (Exception e){
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            try {
                                camera = android.hardware.Camera.open();
                            }catch (RuntimeException ex){}
                            android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters;
                            parameters = camera.getParameters();
                            parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(60);
                            parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_BLACKBOARD);
                            parameters.setPreviewSize(1920, 1080);
                            parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                            camera.setParameters(parameters);
                            cameraId = 0;
                            try {
                                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                                camera.startPreview();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                            }}
                    }
                        else if(moi == 3){
                        moi = 4;
                        if (cameraId == 1){
                            try {
                                camera = android.hardware.Camera.open(1);
                            }catch (RuntimeException ex){}
                            android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters;
                            parameters = camera.getParameters();
                            parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_MONO);
                            parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(60);
                            parameters.setPreviewSize(1920 , 1080);
                            parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                            camera.setParameters(parameters);
                            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                            cameraId = 1;
                            try {
                                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                                camera.startPreview();
                            }catch (Exception e){
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            try {
                                camera = android.hardware.Camera.open();
                            }catch (RuntimeException ex){}
                            android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters;
                            parameters = camera.getParameters();
                            parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(60);
                            parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_MONO);
                            parameters.setPreviewSize(1920, 1080);
                            parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                            camera.setParameters(parameters);
                            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                            cameraId = 0;
                            try {
                                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                                camera.startPreview();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                            }}
                    }
                            else if(moi == 4){
                                moi = 5;
                                if (cameraId == 1){
                                    try {
                                        camera = android.hardware.Camera.open(1);
                                    }catch (RuntimeException ex){}
                                    android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters;
                                    parameters = camera.getParameters();
                                    parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_NEGATIVE);
                                    parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(60);
                                    parameters.setPreviewSize(1920 , 1080);
                                    parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                                    camera.setParameters(parameters);
                                    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                                    cameraId = 1;
                                    try {
                                        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                                        camera.startPreview();
                                    }catch (Exception e){
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    try {
                                        camera = android.hardware.Camera.open();
                                    }catch (RuntimeException ex){}
                                    android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters;
                                    parameters = camera.getParameters();
                                    parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(60);
                                    parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_NEGATIVE);
                                    parameters.setPreviewSize(1920, 1080);
                                    parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                                    camera.setParameters(parameters);
                                    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                                    cameraId = 0;
                                    try {
                                        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                                        camera.startPreview();
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                    }}
                            }
                            else if(moi == 5){
                                moi = 6;
                                if (cameraId == 1){
                                    try {
                                        camera = android.hardware.Camera.open(1);
                                    }catch (RuntimeException ex){}
                                    android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters;
                                    parameters = camera.getParameters();
                                    parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_POSTERIZE);
                                    parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(60);
                                    parameters.setPreviewSize(1920 , 1080);
                                    parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                                    camera.setParameters(parameters);
                                    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                                    cameraId = 1;
                                    try {
                                        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                                        camera.startPreview();
                                    }catch (Exception e){
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    try {
                                        camera = android.hardware.Camera.open();
                                    }catch (RuntimeException ex){}
                                    android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters;
                                    parameters = camera.getParameters();
                                    parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(60);
                                    parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_POSTERIZE);
                                    parameters.setPreviewSize(1920, 1080);
                                    parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                                    camera.setParameters(parameters);
                                    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                                    cameraId = 0;
                                    try {
                                        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                                        camera.startPreview();
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                    }}
                            }
                            else if(moi == 6){
                                moi = 7;
                                if (cameraId == 1){
                                    try {
                                        camera = android.hardware.Camera.open(1);
                                    }catch (RuntimeException ex){}
                                    android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters;
                                    parameters = camera.getParameters();
                                    parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_SOLARIZE);
                                    parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(60);
                                    parameters.setPreviewSize(1920 , 1080);
                                    parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                                    camera.setParameters(parameters);
                                    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                                    cameraId = 1;
                                    try {
                                        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                                        camera.startPreview();
                                    }catch (Exception e){
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    try {
                                        camera = android.hardware.Camera.open();
                                    }catch (RuntimeException ex){}
                                    android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters;
                                    parameters = camera.getParameters();
                                    parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(60);
                                    parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_SOLARIZE);
                                    parameters.setPreviewSize(1920, 1080);
                                    parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                                    camera.setParameters(parameters);
                                    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                                    cameraId = 0;
                                    try {
                                        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                                        camera.startPreview();
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                    }}
                            }

                    }

                    break;
            }
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    }
```

Comment: are u using a virtual device or a real one ?

Comment: i am using real one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using static preview sizes try using supported preview sizes which are introduced in [API level 5](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPreviewSizes%28%29)

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
List<Camera.Size> customSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();


// Choose desired preview size
Camera.Size customSize =  //Added size

parameters.setPreviewSize(customSize.width, customSize.height);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
camera.startPreview();
```

This will be more safer way to use this approach because all devices won't support manual sizes

Comment: What suold be the value of "customSize"?

Comment: @User It would be most suitable preview size for your app use this 
'Camera.Size customSize = customSizes.get(0);'

Answer (score 0):

Its throwing an error probably because of the device you are running/testing on.I had the same issue while working on QRScanner.

Try changing parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(60); and parameters.setPreviewSize(1920 , 1080); as per the device you are using.
Happy Coding